# Add superscript inside \author, problem in IOP template

Tags: author-number, author

I want to use the IOP template from this link:

[IOP Template](http://authors.iop.org/atom/help.nsf/0/B042B0AF79C815B88025702000409514?OpenDocument)

In this template, I have the problem.
 I use the $^1$ inside \authour{}, but in *.pdf file I see the '1' in line, not in superscript.

Here is the latex code

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{jpconf}

\begin{document}
\title[Author guidelines for IOP Publishing journals in  \LaTeXe]{How to `prepare and submit an article for` 
publication in an IOP Publishing journal using \LaTeXe}
\author{Content \& Services Team$^1$}
\address{$^1$ IOP Publishing, Temple Circus, Temple Way, Bristol BS1 6HG, UK}
\ead{submissions@iop.org}
\end{document}
```

Question. How to add the superscript inside the command \author{}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\textsuperscript` can be used to add superscript in text mode.

Try the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{jpconf}

\begin{document}
\title[Author guidelines for IOP Publishing journals in  \LaTeXe]{How to `prepare and submit an article for` 
publication in an IOP Publishing journal using \LaTeXe}
\author{Content \& Services Team \textsuperscript{1}}
\address{$^1$ IOP Publishing, Temple Circus, Temple Way, Bristol BS1 6HG, UK}
\ead{submissions@iop.org}
\end{document}
```